# can't import InverseDataBinding in android

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have below configuration in my gradle file

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
    classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc4'
}
```

I can use `BindingAdapter` annotation but not able to import `InverseBindingAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add `classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc4'`, just enable DataBinding in module level build.gradle file

```
dataBinding {
    enabled true
}
```

you can follow [official docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) for more details